# Java extends Thread not working but implements Runnable does. I don't see why?

Tags: java, multithreading, extend, runnable

I can't believe this is giving me trouble.
My test on `extend Thread` does not work and my `implement Runnable` does. I have compared to working thread code I have written in the past and cannot see what's wrong.

Could someone point out my noob mistake?

**Not working**

```
public class PrimeThread extends Thread
{
    long minPrime;

    public PrimeThread(long minPrime)
    {
        this.minPrime = minPrime;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        PrimeThread p = new PrimeThread(11);
        p.start();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        System.out.println("wtf");
    }
}
```

**Working**

```
public class PrimeRun implements Runnable
{
    long minPrime;
    public PrimeRun(long in)
    {
        minPrime=in;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        PrimeRun p = new PrimeRun(143);       
        new Thread(p).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is not working? exception? just not running etc

Comment: oh no. I just spotted the problem. The Run() method should have lower case r ... run()
:( so embarrassing. 11+ hours a day in the library for the past 8 days is catching up on me.

Comment: That is what the @Override annotation is for, so it will clue you in to that kind of error. :-)  It's extremely rare to have a good reason to extend Thread and it's too easy to mess up, so in general it's better to stay away from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your "Run" method is capitalized. So it's a different method (i.e. you're not overriding "run")

Comment: Luckily I am the only developer on the planet who has not spent hours or days staring at a mistake like that and scratching my head. I"m so glad that's never happened to me. Wouldn't know what that's like at all ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just edit your method name to be `run` instead of `Run`